# Are there examples of taildragger autoland systems?

Tags: tail-dragger, autoland

I have only been able to find examples of auto-land systems for tricycle gear. Is there an equivalent for taildraggers?

I realize taildraggers are more commonly used in VFR conditions, so there may not be a sufficient market draw solely based on the weather argument (as would be the case for e.g. commercial air transport). I also realize that taildragger aircraft tend to cost less, thus making it harder to justify investment in an avionics capability that would likely be expensive. But are there any other reasons why they are so much less common (if they exist at all)? The physics would be different, but modern control systems are capable of handling those...

**Follow-Up Feb 23:** Since there seem to be no obvious examples - and in light of the constraints identified above and in John K's answer - what would be the simplest (read: cheapest) taildragger auto-land system that would provide meaningful benefit (e.g. prevent ground loops)? For example, would a simple "Heading Hold Mode" augmentation system be helpful? If not, why not?

**Fun Fact:** The closest to a "landing system" that I could find is [Brodie Landing System](https://youtu.be/7Wrz20iLAEA?t=9m) for the L-4, discussed [here](https://generalaviationnews.com/2017/08/23/8-random-facts-about-the-piper-cub/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any tailwheel airplanes with the level of sophistication that would make it even worthwhile doing.

It could be done in theory but would require a much more sophisticated system because taildraggers are considerably more demanding to land and to control on the ground (they are dynamically unstable while rolling on the ground and want to switch ends - try pushing a shopping cart backwards really fast).  There just isn't a market that would even take an interest in developing it.

Comment: It seems to me that being dynamically unstable would make it even more attractive for a control system? The [X-29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_X-29) comes mind...

Comment: Point is I'm not aware of any taildragger airplanes where one would even think of certifying Autoland.  There are very few that fly IFR at all... Beech 18s, DC-3s, from time to time.  Think anybody's gonna develop an autoland for the DC-3?  Might as well include a booster rocket for low orbit as well.

Comment: The important point is that autoland currently means ILS and when that is constructed, the runway can also be paved, but the only practical advantage of tail-draggers I can think of is for rough fields.